# Сортировка многомерного массива по ключу и его значению PHP

Tags: php

Здраствуйте ,возник вопрос по массивам , точнее его сортировки.
Есть многомерный массив вида:

```
 return array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Главная',
            'url' => 'http://pegas-cms.localhost/',
            'num' => 0,
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Блог',
            'url' => 'http://pegas-cms.localhost/blog/',
            'num' => 0,
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Список вопросов',
            'url' => 'http://pegas-cms.localhost/feedback/list',
            'num' => 0,
            'child' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Список вопросов',
                    'url' => 'http://pegas-cms.localhost/feedback/list',
                    'tooltip' => 'Список вопросов',
                    'num' => 0,
            ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Добавить вопрос',
                    'url' => 'http://pegas-cms.localhost/feedback/themes/add',
                    'num' => 0,
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Поиск вопроса',
                    'url' => 'http://pegas-cms.localhost/feedback/search/?newsearch=1',
                    'num' => 0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
     );
```

Как отсортировать весь массив ,чтобы в массиве в самом верху были массивы с наименьшим параметром num
Какие есть варианты? Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

usort
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php

Comment: массив остается прежним в независимости от num ,пробывал с данной функцией/

Answer (score 4):

Сортировка это просто!

```
usort($array, function($a,$b){
    return ($a['num']-$b['num']);
});
```

Cсылку давали.

Comment: хватит просто 

    return ($a['num']-$b['num']);

Comment: ну кстати да. Надо поправить

Comment: да фильтрует правильно ,это у меня косяк был не тот массив возращал и проверял ( спасибо добрые люди вы мне очень помогли )

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я понимаю приведенные выше ответы с

```
return ($a['num']-$b['num']);
```

подходят только для ключей со значениями integer? Поправте если я неправильно понимаю сортировку.
Для себя написал простенькую функцию работающую и со строковыми значениями:

```
/**
 * Сортируем многомерный массив по значению вложенного массива
 * @param $array array многомерный массив который сортируем
 * @param $field string название поля вложенного массива по которому необходимо отсортировать
 * @return array отсортированный многомерный массив
 */
function customMultiSort($array,$field) {
    $sortArr = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        $sortArr[$key] = $val[$field];
    }

    array_multisort($sortArr,$array);

    return $array;
}
```

Прошу критиковать по существу, а не сыпать разными вариациями одного и того же, в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) есть и другие варианты.